# Blender normals problem

Tags: modeling, modifiers, normals, unity

So, I have an object to which I preformed a boolean operation. The problem is that by doing that, some of the normals on the object are facing the wrong direction:

[image]

Now, the object looks fine in blender, but when exported to Unity, since faces cannot be double-sided, they appear facing the wrong direction and appear invisible:

[image]

So I tried recalculating the normals to see if it would fix that problem, which it did, but it created another one:[image]

Now the object looks very weird and lit wrong, and I have no clue what's wrong. I've recalculated the normals again, I've flipped only the normals in the door part, but nothing seems to fix it. If someone can help I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Well don't I feel stupid now... Thanks a lot, I'm a bit of a noob as you can see and I had no idea.

Comment: Hello :). Please mark the asnwer as accepted **✓**, for others with a similar problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The edges of the door arc aren't marked sharp like the other edges that are colored light blue. You can either mark these edges as well (select the edges then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> *> Mark Sharp*) or set the shading to flat for the entire mesh.